# Download or pull a file from azure git repo using rest api

Tags: java, azure-devops-rest-api

My requirement is to Download / pull a file from azure git repo And convert it to a byte Array. I searched in Azure git repo API but I couldn't found the rest api call. Please help to get the solution.

I tried with the below url but it's returning unicode value in content object.

GET https://dev.azure.com{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&versionDescriptor.version={versionDescriptor.version}&versionDescriptor.versionType={versionDescriptor.versionType}&includeContent=true&api-version=6.0

Comment: Hi Harshita, Do below answers work for you? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you saying you want to use a get request from Microsoft azure? I would maybe recommend using fetch to retrieve your data. something along the lines of:

```
fetch("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect? returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=emotion&recognitionModel= 
   recognition_01&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection_01"
            , {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<subscription key>'
                },
                body: makeblob(contents)
            }).then((response) => response.json()).then(success => {
                that.setState({selectedFile: url1});

            that.setState({facesArray: success});
            console.log("facesArray is", that.state.facesArray);
            console.log("new selected state is", that.state.selectedFile);
            // console.log(success);
        }).catch(error =>
            console.log("did not work ",error))
```

I understand i'm using a post request, but if you change the subscription key, body, fetch url, and content type, you might be able to get what your are looking for. Also, you can somehow contact microsoft azure services for more help on their api.

Comment: I am using Azure devops git repo.

Comment: @Harshita It shouldn't matter. You need an HTTP library to perform your GET request. Just make sure you are authenticated as necessary. Do you need help making a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Make sure you add `httpclient` to your gradle/madle build. Replace `azurePathString` with your URL.

```
public byte[] executeBinary(URI uri) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(azurePathString);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    entity.writeTo(baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use API: `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&versionDescriptor.version={versionDescriptor.version}&download=true&api-version=6.0` to download the target file, and then read this file and convert its content to a byte Array. See: [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#download) for more details.

Comment: Hi Harshita, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.